# Set current admin user as user to save in db under Django Admin TabularInline

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a `TabularInline` under my admin page, and I want to prevent admins from editing `submit_user` field by making it read-only.

However when creating a new entries in database, I need to be able to pass the current user as `submit_user`

I've read many posts on stackoverflow but none of them works for me. Many suggested `save_formset` but it's simply not working for me. The db always complains about not having the `submit_user` field (if this case, the column has a ForeignKey that maps to another table `User`, and the complaint is about user_id. Thought have the user object should be fine, but it doesn't seem like it's the case.)

my model looks like

```
class SomeTable(model.Model):
    submit_user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='user')
    data1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I sorta cheated but solved my issue. Since the table is asking for id instead of user object, I pass in `request.user.id` instead.

Here's what it looks like

```
instances = formset.save(commit=False)
for i in instances:
    i.submit_user_id = request.user.id
    i.save()
formset.save_m2m()
```

EDIT 1:

This is the final version of my answer. I could successfully add and delete entry with this rewrite of `save_formset`

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
    instances = formset.save(commit=False)
    for i in instances:
        if hasattr(i, 'submit_user_id') and not i.submit_user_id:
            i.submit_user_id = request.user.id
        i.save()

    formset.save_m2m()
    super(SomeModelAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

Comment: solved by adding `super(MerchantAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)` right after `def save_formset`